# Sharing and caching common resources for SVG images inserted as objects

Tags: html, svg, web, fonts, browser-cache

There are several SVG images inserted using `<object>` tag in [here](http://drifted.in/other/svg/css-test-case/).

The main reasons for choosing this tag is:

- to keep image resources in separate files
- to ensure all fonts are resolved properly

By default fonts are not inherited from the main web page to the linked SVG images, however, when the style reference `<?xml-stylesheet href="main.css" type="text/css"?>` with the font definition is inserted into that SVG image, it is resolved properly in case of `<object>` tag.

However, when multiple images share the same `css` file, pointing to same `woff` font resource, it is loaded again and again by the browser. Even the same SVG image inserted as object is not cached and loaded again and again.

How can I ensure the font is loaded only once for multiple images?

I'd like to avoid inline SVG as real images are rather huge and couldn't be cached.

Comment: You could try to load the css once from the main page, convert it to a Blob and create a blobURI from it, then, still from the main page, insert the stylesheet link pointing to this blobURI into all your objects' document. If it is not clear, I'll try to write you answer tomorrow since I don't have access to a keyboard right now.

Comment: Ps: you may also consider using iframes, which may not have this object's bug in the specs I never understood about caching.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use an `<iframe>` which doesn't have this weird *no-cache*  behavior `<object>` suffers from.

[http:// Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/njnuqrbt/) using your svg file, since stacksnippet's https:// frames won't allow the loading of your font file.

The main caveat with this workaround is that the `<iframe>` won't set its size itself to the one of your document like `<object>` does, so you would have to set it yourself.

- Either you know it before hand, and can just set it in the CSS,
- either you set it as an attribute and your svg files are from the same-origin, in which case you can [grab it from the iframe's contentDocument](http://plnkr.co/edit/K6ocFy7kUxYTZ5HeMWkO?p=preview),
- either you load it in an Image and [grab it from there](http://jsfiddle.net/njnuqrbt/2/).